# Magento 2: How to move Details tab to product info column?

Tags: magento2, product, blocks, theme, design

In Magento 2, the Blank theme displays the **Details** tabs below product images.

How to move this block to the product info column (right side of the page, under **Add to cart** button)?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We should take a look at: `vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/layout/catalog_product_view.xml` line 103 ~ 118

```
<block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.description" template="product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                ......
</block>
```

All tabs are inside the `product.info.details` element and belong to group `detailed_info`. The add-to-cart element belongs to `product_options_wrapper_bottom` element. We need to rearrange these elements. To do this, add the extending `catalog_product_view.xml` in the `app/design/frontend/{Vendor Theme}/{Theme Name}/Magento_Catalog/layout/` directory:

```
#app/design/frontend/{Vendor Theme}/{Theme Name}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <move element="product.info.details" destination="product.info.main" after="product_options_wrapper_bottom"/>
    </body>
</page>
```

Here is the result:
[image]

You can read more here: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.0/frontend-dev-guide/layouts/xml-manage.html#layout_markup_rearrange

Comment: That worked. I only had to make one small change. I left out the `layout="2columns-left"` part, since the default value is `1column`. Thanks

Comment: Now I want the "related products" block, displays through **full width** of screen (now this block displays **half screen** under gallery image). Is it possible to do this via layout changes only? I hope you can help. Thanks

Comment: I think it's better if you post in a new question, I will follow your question.

Comment: I just posted the question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/128637/how-to-make-related-up-sell-products-display-full-width-of-screen