# How to make related/up sell products display full width of screen?

Tags: magento2, layout, design

In product page, product details tab appear below the images gallery along the full width of screen. Related products appear below the details tabs.

If details are moved to the right column (below the 'Add to cart' button), the related products block shrinks half screen.

**How to make the related products block remain full width of screen?**

Comment: please share ,your source code?

Comment: In the `catalog_product_view.xml` file from my theme, I've only added the following line to move the details tabs to the right column: `<move element="product.info.details" destination="product.info.main" after="product_options_wrapper_bottom"/>`.

Comment: @AmitBera could you help?

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix is to set the CSS property `clear: right` for the upsell products block.

I still would like to understand why the upsell products block shrinks to half screen when details tabs `product.info.details` are moved to the `product.info.main` block.