# Magento2 blocks change

Tags: magento2, product-view, page

How to change details.phtml file under addto.phtml file or we wants to change the design in magento2 product view page.

Answer (score -1):

Please follow the link below:

Its worked for me,
[Magento 2: How to move Details tab to product info column?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112376/magento-2-how-to-move-details-tab-to-product-info-column)

## app/design/frontend/{Vendor Theme}/{Theme Name}/Magento_Catalog/layout/catalog_product_view.xml

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  layout="2columns-left" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
<body>
    <move element="product.info.details" destination="product.info.main" after="product_options_wrapper_bottom"/>
</body>
```