# Move product info in details tab

Tags: magento2, layout, xml, magento2.2.4

I basically want to move the tabs in the product info area. But within the details tab I want all the content of product.info. So I have tried to move the info section which has all short description add to buttons and sku to the details tab. But I am not able to move.

```
<move element="product.info.main" destination="product.attributes"/>

<move element="product.info.main" destination="product.info.description"/>

<move element="product.info.main" destination="product.info.details"/>
```

Are what I have tried. Can someone help?

Comment: can you try this : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/112376/magento-2-how-to-move-details-tab-to-product-info-column?rq=1

Comment: Actually that was done, There ws a module which was creating its own tabs block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try below code , i think you want to show 
***short description, add to cart and sku*** into product tab
and want to move tab into product info section.

Need to work on

> *`catalog_product_view.xml file`*

```
   <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.details" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/details.phtml" after="product.info.media">
                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.overview1" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getShortDescription</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">short_description</argument>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">shortdescription</argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="shortdescription"</argument>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Product shortdescription</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>
                 <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description" name="product.info.sku1" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/attribute.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="at_call" xsi:type="string">getSku</argument>
                        <argument name="at_code" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">sku</argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                        <argument name="add_attribute" xsi:type="string">itemprop="sku"</argument>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Product SKU</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>

                <block class="Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View" name="product.info.addtocart.additional1" template="Magento_Catalog::product/view/addtocart.phtml" group="detailed_info">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="css_class" xsi:type="string">product-options-bottom</argument>
                        <argument name="at_label" xsi:type="string">none</argument>
                        <argument name="title" translate="true" xsi:type="string">Add to Cart</argument>
                    </arguments>
                </block>

                </block>

<move element="product.info.details" destination="product.info.main" after="-"/>
```